# How to make variables optional while concatenation of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am manipulating string to display in UI, Data is being dynamically with below code sometime i don't get `header` and `details` so how to make `IHeader` and `IResponse` optional for the string concatenation below.

if i dont have IHeader it will break at IHeader.id and throw exception i want to display whatever data is available to render.

main.js

```
const data = [{
    id: "header",
    name: "IHeader"
}, {
    id: "param",
    name: "IParams"
}, {
    id: "details",
    name: "IResponse"
}]

function buildText(data) {
    var IParams;
    var IResponse;
    var IHeader;
    for (var item of data) {
        if (item.id === "param") {
            IParams = item;
        } else if (item.id === "header") {
            IHeader = item;
        } else if (item.id === "details") {
            IResponse = item;
        }
    }
    var text = '';
    text += app + '.setConfig({\n' + "env:" + getEnv() + '\n});' + '\n\n';
    text += 'let param:' + IParams.name + ' ' + '=' + '' + JSON.stringify(request, null, 4) + ';\n\n';
    text += ref + '(' + 'param,(result:' + ' ' + '{' + '\n' + IHeader.id + ':' + IHeader.name + '\n' + IResponse.id + ':' + IResponse.name + '\n' + '})' + ' ' +
        ' => {\n  console.log(result); \n});';

}
```

Comment: so build the string inside the ifs instead of setting variables....

Comment: Use object and [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: @User863 i tried IHeader[id] or IHeader["id"] both didn't work it still throws id is undefined

Answer (score 0):

**1** - You can try to create an object with empty values. That'll prevent the exception.

```
   emptyObject = {id: ""} // more empty keys, if there is
   IParam = (item.id === "param") ? item : emptyObject
```

**2** - Or ignore that concatenation of the variable if `undefined` or `null`.

```
if (Iparam) {
    // concatenation ..
}
```